# Self-signed SSL not working on workstation

Tags: ssl, tomcat, self-signed

I'm tinkering with a self-signed certificate on RH Linux 7 for a tomcat instance, but having a hell of a time so that I don't have browser warnings. I've followed this guys instructions here ([Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)) and tried importing the .crt into my tomcat instance using keytool. Using the following commands -

Create the keystore - keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore

Import the myCA.pem file created in the stackoverflow steps - keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file myCA.pem

And finally import the .crt created from the stackoverflow - keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file signed.crt

Now on the Linux 7 box I can access server.domain.com:8443 or server:8443 with a warning, but on my Windows workstation I can only access server:8443, not the FQDN. I've imported both the myCa.pem and signed.crt into my computer as trusted root authorities.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand is . You have generated SSL certs and imported in you machine. 
Hope you have updated the conf/server.xml with ssl information . After updating restart the service and check